# celery (flask) running worker /incorrect name

Tags: python, flask, celery

I've got problems running the celery worker process.
my python code (test.py):

```
from flask import *
from celery import *


def main():
    #flask related code
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

    celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    @celery.task
        def my_background_task(arg1, arg2):
            f = open('file.txt','w')
            f.write('answer:'+str(arg1))
            f.close()
            return 1

    @app.route('/createServer', methods=['POST'])
         def createServer():
             task = my_background_task.apply_async(args=["test0", "test1"], countdown=10)
             return jsonify({"status": "done"})

    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the worker using

```
celery worker -A test --broker=redis://127.0.0.1:6379  --loglevel=info
```

and a new command is inserted I get this error

```
[2017-04-22 18:02:09,184: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'__init__.my_background_task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[["test0", "test1"], {}, {"chord": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null}]' (93b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 559, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: u'__init__.my_background_task'
```

What's wrong? It seems like this is because of my main() handling? Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what's the name of your file?

Comment: test.py is the name of my python file containing this code.

Comment: Try running: `celery worker -A test -l info -c 5`. BTW, why is wrapping your code inside the main function necessary?

Comment: This seems much better, if you could tell me now how to change the driver from amqp to redis all would be fine ;). Currently I get: `[2017-04-22 17:53:38,124: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds...`.

Comment: What version of celery are you using? In my cases, I just pass the redis url and it works.

Comment: If you are using ```redis```  try you this ```sudo service redis restart``` that issue is because your ```message broker.``` does not work or try you this ```/etc/init.d/redis-server restart```

Comment: I updated code above. Got the worker running, but it seems like my way of using the main function causes some problems.

Comment: which version of python you are use?

Comment: @julian salas python 2.7

Comment: @kreishna seems be issue with import relative check out doc of celery http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports, add top every module the next : ```from __future__ import absolute_import```

Comment: I've included this import to the top of the script, but I still receive the same error when running the worker listener and inserting a new job.

Answer (score 0):

The worker needs to be able to import the task function from the module where it was defined, which is not possible when it's nested inside another scope (in this case inside the `main` function).

Try defining your tasks in the main scope:

```
    @celery.task
    def my_background_task(arg1, arg2):
        ...

    def main():
        ...
```

Comment: When I use this code, trying to run the worker using: `celery worker -A test --broker=redis://127.0.0.1:6379  --loglevel=info` I get: `File "/home/csgo/server_manager/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    @celery.task
NameError: name 'celery' is not defined` Because celery is defined inside the main (as you see above). Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Just move the initialisation outside as well: `celery = Celery(__name__, broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')`. You can keep `celery.conf.update(app.config)` inside the function.